# React-Native & async functions: Setting conditional value

Tags: react-native, async-await, callback, conditional-statements

I'm trying to return a conditional value for the iconColor prop. If the value isFav returns true I'd like to set the iconColor to red, otherwise it should be white. I have assigned the variable red a hex value, and white (string) is recognized by the style library I'm using. Despite isFav() returning false (I've logged the value), iconColor is always red. Do you know why that would be?

Thanks for your help!

```
 async function isFav(title) {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(title)
    if (value) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function _renderItem({ item }, navigation) {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigation.navigate("oneRecipe", {item: item})}>
        <View style={styles.recipesItem}>
          <CardTextComponent
            imageUri={item.image}
            title={item.title}
            subtitle={`Your Ingredients: ${item.usedIngredientCount}`}
            showFavs={true}
            iconColor={(async() => isFav()) ? red : "white"}
          />
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a state instead?

```
const [isFav, setIsFav] = useState(false);

const _isFav = async ()=> {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(title)
    if (value) {
      return setIsFav(true);
    }
    return setIsFav(false);
}

useEffect(()=>{
    _isFav()
},[])

const _renderItem = ({ item }, navigation)=> {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigation.navigate("oneRecipe", {item: item})}>
        <View style={styles.recipesItem}>
          <CardTextComponent
            imageUri={item.image}
            title={item.title}
            subtitle={`Your Ingredients: ${item.usedIngredientCount}`}
            showFavs={true}
            iconColor={ isFav ? "red" : "white"}
          />
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
```